# BigQuery select statement fails using Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to retrieve data from my BigQuery table inside a Cloud Functions that is triggered by pubsub.

When I run this function inside cloud shell terminal it works perfectly, but inside Cloud functions it does something weird. When a query is run BiqQuery will save a log under PROJECT HISTORY. Its either a green check mark or a red exclamation mark.[image]

Inside the Cloud Function logs I noticed that the function execution ends before even the code is done.

[image: cloud function log]

What I don't understand is Inside BigQuery log I believe that my query fails, but indside Cloud Functions log it still returns the values.

> index.js

```
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

exports.telemetryToBigQueryV2 = (data) => {

    const Select_result_query = `SELECT * FROM \`pti-tag-copy.Download.result\` WHERE Tag="tag-2"`; //output: False, tag-2, belgium, 2
    console.log(`this is the Select_result query: ${Select_result_query}`);

    let Tag_data = createJob(Select_result_query);
    console.log(`This is Tag_data result: ${Tag_data}`);


    let result;
    let returned_tag;
    let returned_location;
    let returned_poleId;

    Promise.resolve(Tag_data).then((v) => {
        result = v.Result
        returned_tag = v.Tag
        returned_location = v.Location
        returned_poleId = v.PoleId
        console.log(`this is result: ${v.Result}`);
        console.log(`this is tag: ${v.Tag}`);
        console.log(`this is location: ${v.Location}`);
        console.log(`this is poleid: ${v.PolId}`);
    });

}

async function createJob(query) {
    // Run a BigQuery query job.


    // For all options, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job
    const options = {
        configuration: {
            query: {
                query: query,
                useLegacySql: false,
            },
            location: 'EU'
        },
    };

    try {
        console.log(`calling createJob`)
        const [job] = await bigquery.createJob(options);
        console.log(`this is select the job: ${job}`);

        console.log(`Calling getQueryResults`)
        const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();


        if (rows.length < 1) {
            console.log("array is empty");
        } else {
            console.log("Array is full retuning data");
            return {
                Result: rows[0]["Result"],
                Tag: rows[0]["Tag"],
                Location: rows[0]["Location"],
                PolId: rows[0]["PolId"]
            }
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Something went wrong + ${error}`)

    }
}
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "telemetryToBigQueryV2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.18.0",
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "5.9.1"
  }
}
```

I followed the examples: [BigQuery docs: Create a job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-create-job) and [Query with the BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-simple-app-all#bigquery_simple_app_all-nodejs)

Am I doing something wrong with promises? If so than at least the BigQuery logs should show a green checkmark or am I wrong?

How can I fix this issue? Please say anything that might help. I am stuck for a while now.

Comment: Promise is async. Use a sync mechanism to wait the end of the query and then respond to the request (I'm bad in NodeJS, I can only advice to use await as proposed in the documentation)

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere After posting the question I did put async before my main function. I thought it was only necessary for the selectJob, but now I understand that async should be used everywhere where there is a promise. Now the function does what it should do, but inside BigQuery I still get a red exclamation mark in the logs but it does return the correct values from BigQuery.

Comment: When it fails, what does it contain the BigQuery log with the red icon? If you click on the red icon what does it show you?

Comment: it doesn't show anything.  Normally when something fails it tells me but with cloud functions it doesn't

Comment: Then I would recommend you to contact Google Cloud Platform technical [support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) as they would be able to get more insights